# datagrid view with 2 data sources

Tags: wpf, data-binding, custom-controls

I'm writing an app where i want to compare the data from two different data sources to see if there are any differences. All examples i have seen of similar functionality always place two datagrids  next to each other so that you can see each row side by side.

This makes it very hard to spot differences.  What i would like to do is to show the rows one above the other in agridview.  That is, alternate the rows in the datagrid to be bound to one then the other datasource as a matched pair.  Actually i would also like to add a check box to one row so that the pair can be selected for futher processing.

I know that the controls are very customisable but is something like this possible ?  Or would i need to combine the two data sources into a single one and then bind it ?

Comment: Notwithstanding the supplied answer you might also want to consider taking a different approach here.  Computers are much more reliable than humans when it comes to comparing data.  So could you possibly just have the program code detect the differences and then display those mismatches in a grid for further review.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is [MultiBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx)

This will enable you to bind multiple items and by using a converter to return a new single item. So essentially, yes, you will combine the two data sources into one inside the converter.

Comment: Ok, i had a read of the Multibinding class but as far as I can tell it takes the imput from multiple sources and based on logic you setup in your Convert method creates a single ouput value  you then bind.

Comment: what i want it have both values bound and show up in alternating rows. e.g row a from table1 row b from table2 then row c from table1 again etc etc

Comment: I don't THINK you can do that, but I can't say for sure as I never really tried; if you plan to try MultiBinding you can combine the two tables and have alternating rows inside your "combined object" which is then returned by the converter. I can't see how an element would be able to resolve having multiple sources natively without a converter to be honest.